# I want to enter test scores from merged excel files into a number column

Tags: excel

=IF(B2=$C$1, C2, IF(B2=$D$1, D2, IF(B2 =$E$1,E2, IF(B2=$F$1,F2))))

```
 #  Answer A  B  C  D  number
1    A     2  1  3  0   2
2    B     1  5  0  0   5
```

i have 100 questions

Comment: And what is your questio the formula looks good

Comment: Question is quiet unclear. What you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is not clear, it seems you are trying to achieve number column by matching answer column. You can try `INDEX/MATCH` following way.

```
=INDEX(B2:E2,,MATCH(A2,$B$1:$E$1,0))
```

[image]